# First known author to use the concept of "Bigger on the inside"

Tags: history-of, trope

Who namely known author used the concept of being bigger on the inside first? A holodeck is bigger on the inside, the TARDIS is, on Diskworld the Home of Death and Rincewind's Luggage are, Hermione's handbag is... Or think of this beautifully crafted excample from ENT "Future Tense"

[image: Timeship: Bigger on the inside too]

It's a known [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BiggerOnTheInside), and can be traced back to 1001 nights.

**But who was the first *known author* to use the concept for speculative fiction?**

Comment: @DVK Thanks for the edit! I hope things are clearer that way. Indeed I'm looking for the **name** of an **author**.

Comment: You could argue that every story that deals with infinite space are subtropes, because if they are in our world, they must be visible. I don't know the first story that deals with infinite size though.

Comment: @SebastianSchmitz I agree with your reasoning - to a degree: It's not what I intended to ask but I agree it's what I actually did ask. Anyway: If you you come up with an early infinte-size-story I'll surly consider it a legit answer (and would be interested to read it)!

Comment: I would argue that a holodeck isn't bigger on the inside, it just looks like it is

Comment: Of the examples you give, the TARDIS is by far the oldest, since it dates back to the first season of Doctor Who, which aired in 1963.

Comment: The Last Battle(1956) by C.S. Lewis had a slightly different concept of nested worlds, with each inner layer larger than the one outside it.

Comment: @user20310 That depends on which epistemological approach you choose. If you view it from a phenomenological point (just take into account what you _perceive_) it is bigger on the inside. However: Though you are right, I just wanted to illustrate the concept, to provide a perspective on how far spread this concept is.

Comment: Where is the trope used in *1,001 Nights*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Charles Howard Hinton (1853-1907), a mathematician and writer, was a big influence on dimension based speculative science fiction work. He wrote [several short stories and essays](http://www.eldritchpress.org/chh/hinton.html) that laid out a lot of the scientific framework for dimensionality in literature. Some of these were based on the concepts of Flatland (1884), which was 2 dimensional, and expanded on them.

Hinton's intention in his writing, fiction and non-fiction, was to provide a stronger scientific basis for the concept of extra-dimensional space since this was becoming a common topic in the mid-to-late 1800's.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Carroll and Wilde are more describing "doorways" - don't they? I mean Alice is not really _inside_ the rabbit hole... The Hinton-hint (no pun intended) is just great! If no-one comes up with something pre-dating that, this is the right answer, I guess!

Comment: @Einer I agree, I would remove the first paragraph entirely, since it is just wrong and detracts from an otherwise quite good answer!

Comment: I've modified it, although Alice in Wonderland ( and Through the Looking Glass) dealt with a number dimension bending topics beyond just the rabbit hole. Exactly what those worlds are, Carroll left it up to the dreams of his readers.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if earliest, but *[Master and Margarita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Master_and_Margarita)* by Bulgakov used the trope. The publication date is 1966 but the novel itself was writrten between 1928 and 1940.

It's not easy to find which year he included the idea of "Using the familiarity with 5th dimension to turn a small Soviet apartment into Voland's ballroom" but 1940 is the upper limit.

Comment: Sounds like a novel I should know about. I certainly have some catching up to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Jaroslav Hasek's "Good soldier Svejk" (cca 1923), chapter 4:

> ... and the other explained to me that inside the globe there was another globe much bigger than the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

The Wardrobe in CS Lewis "The Lion The Witch and the Wardrobe" predates the TARDIS by some time.   Lewis also uses a device rather akin to wormholes to jump into different worlds with different time flow rates in "The Magician's Nephew", breathtaking ideas given how long ago they were written.

Comment: And in neither case are they objects that are bigger on the inside, they are doorways to another world.